# PHP Memcached isset

Tags: php, memcached, isset

Any idea if PHP's memcached module supports some kind of `isset()` method?

Following case:

```
Memcached::set('foo', false);

if(Memcached::get('foo') === false) {
        // Set or not set?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[according to the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.get.php)

```
if($memcached->get('var') === false && $memcached->getResultCode() == Memcached::RES_NOTFOUND){
   //not set
}
```

You can of course extend the `Memcached` object to include it, however, you can't ask if it's set without getting it (some overhead on larger values):

```
class YourMemcached extends Memcached {
    function var_isset($var){
       return $this->get($var)!==false || $this->getResultCode() != Memcached::RES_NOTFOUND;
    }
}
```

(you can't use `isset` as a method name as it's a language construct apparently).